# jQuery TinySort can't select divs to sort them, or something else is blocking the sort

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, tinysort

I'm trying to have the jQuery plugin [TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) sort divs by the href attribute of their links.
The divs I want sortable ("box") are divided evenly within two separate divs ("row1" and "row 2") and these two divs are within another div ("projects").  I.E., the sortable div is three levels down form the parent element.

My function is a simple click event to sort:

```
$("#sortname").click(function(){
$(".box").tsort("a",{order:"desc",attr:"href"});
});
```

I thought this meant:

When #sortname is clicked, all .box will sort in descending order by the href attribute of the link contained there-in.  In reality, nothing happens when it is clicked.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

I also tried

```
$(".box > div").tsort("a",{order:"desc",attr:"href"});
```

and

```
$(".box div").tsort("a",{order:"desc",attr:"href"});
```

to select divs that are children and descendents of .box, but those didn't work either.

HTML:

```
<h1 id="sortname">Sort By Name</h1>
<div id="projects">
<div class="row1">   
<div class="box">  
<a href="project1.htm"><img class="project1" src="project1"/></a>   
<div class="caption"><a href="project1.htm">Project 1</a></div>
</div>

<div class="box">  
<a href="project2.htm"><img class="project2" src="project2"/></a>   
<div class="caption"><a href="project2.htm">Project 2</a></div>
</div>

<div class="box">  
<a href="project3.htm"><img class="project3" src="project3"/></a>   
<div class="caption"><a href="project3.htm">Project 3</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row2">     
<div class="box">  
<a href="project4.htm"><img class="project4" src="project4"/></a>   
<div class="caption"><a href="project4.htm">Project 4</a></div>
</div>

<div class="box">  
<a href="project5.htm"><img class="project5" src="project5"/></a>   
<div class="caption"><a href="project5.htm">Project 5</a></div>
</div>

<div class="box">  
<a href="project6.htm"><img class="project6" src="project6"/></a>   
<div class="caption"><a href="project6.htm">Project 6</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not sort the way you want to because you've nested the .box in different parents (.row1 and .row2). The sort will work, but the .box nodes will always stay inside their parent node.
Just leave out those parent rows and you should be fine by sorting:

```
$('.box').tsort('a',{attr:'href'});
```

You will not need the .row parents anyway. Use one parent with a fixed width and use nth-child to set the margins for the child .box

Comment: Note that tinysort v2 sorts over different parents by default